# SQL count with having clause wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand how to count mysql row's according to HAVING.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  SUM(CASE WHEN sentby='$user_id' AND hiddenbysentby=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sentbyuser,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sentto='$user_id' AND hiddenbysentto=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as senttouser
  FROM cb_users.user_pm
  WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'
  HAVING senttouser = 1 OR sentbyuser = 1
```

I want to count rows that are matching these criteria

```
SUM(CASE WHEN sentby='$user_id' AND hiddenbysentby=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

SUM(CASE WHEN sentto='$user_id' AND hiddenbysentto=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I have second function that display this data without COUNT(*), and it works fine.

But this query selects all rows no matter if hiddenbysentby = 1 or 0 AND hiddenbysentto = 1 or 0

Comment: Where filters the selected rows, having filters the output. In your query the count is over all records with tile containing search.

Comment: Usage of `having` without `group by` will definitely have some unintended behaviour at times

Answer (score 0):

You should move condition by hiddenbysentby and hiddenbysentto fields in WHERE clause and add a condition by user id

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  SUM(CASE WHEN sentby='$user_id' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sentbyuser,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sentto='$user_id' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as senttouser
  FROM cb_users.user_pm
  WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' AND (hiddenbysentby=0 AND sentby='$user_id') OR (hiddenbysentto=0 AND sentto='$user_id')
  HAVING senttouser = 1 OR sentbyuser = 1
```

Comment: 1.Why my query works without count(*)? 2.if sentto = user and hiddenbysentby = 1 it will display wrong result too.

Comment: @ArtisUļjanovs, 1. Your query doesn't work, because you find all records in the table and calculate count() by them.  2. I updated my answer, try to run the modified query again

Answer (score 0):

You should change your HAVING clause to:

HAVING senttouser >= 1 OR sentbyuser >= 1

When you are summing rows, your values are going to equal the total number of rows located for each, therefore, unless you only had exactly one row that meets your criteria, you won't get the result you're looking for.

Comment: It dosn't change anything. Because senttouser and sentbyuser can be only 1 or 0